# Nuxt.js env Property, understanding and how to use it?

Tags: vue.js, axios, environment-variables, nuxt.js, apollo

following https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env

I have been trying to set up my apiUrl in `nuxt.config.js` **once** for the whole project, like:

```
export default {
  env: {
    apiUrl: process.env.MY_REMOTE_CMS_API_URL || 'http://localhost:1337'
  }
}
```

adding this in **nuxt.config.js**, I'd expect (and would like) to have **apiUrl** accessible *everywhere* in the project. 
In particular, it is needed for the 3 following cases:

1. with **axios**, to generate static pages from dynamic urls (in `nuxt.config.js`)

   ```
   generate: {
      routes: function () {
         return axios.get(apiUrl + '/posts')
           .then((res) => {
             return res.data.filter(page => {
               return page.publish === true;
             }).map(page => {
               return {
                 route: '/news/' + page.slug
               }
             })
           })
       }
     },
   ```
2. with **apollo**, to get data via graphql (in `nuxt.config.js`)

   ```
     apollo: {
       clientConfigs: {
         default: {
           httpEndpoint: apiUrl + '/graphql'
         }
       }
     },
   ```
3. in **every** layout, page and components, as the base url of media:

   ```
   <img :src="apiUrl + item.image.url" />
   ```

As you might see, only thing I need is to 'print' the actual base url of the cms.
I have also tried to access it with `process.env.apiUrl`, with no success.

The only way I was able to make it has been to create an extra `plugin/apiUrl.js` file, which injects the api url, and seems wrong to me as I am now setting the apiUrl twice in my project.

I asked this question in the past, but in a way less clear way. I was suggested to use dotenv, but from the docs it looks like adding an additional layer of complication that might not be necessary for a simpler setup.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Nuxt 2.13, @nuxtjs/dotenv is not required anymore. [Read here](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config)

The concept that I was missing is that you set up the same named variable in your server / pipeline, so that you have your (always local / never pushed) .env file and a same name variable remotely, not added to your repo (where the value can be the same or different)

Answer (score 2):

I think dotenv module really is what you need.

This is my setup:

- Project root has a .env file that contains
  BASE_URL=https://www.myapi.com
- `require('dotenv').config()` at top of nuxt.config.js
- `@nuxtjs/dotenv` installed and added to `buildModules` of nuxt.config.js
- `env: { BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL}` added to nuxt.config.js
- `axios: { baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL }` added to nuxt.config.js (optional)

You should have access to your .env throughout the project. (process.env.BASE_URL)

I haven't used apollo, but you should be able to set the apollo endpoint with `process.env.BASE_URL + '/graphql'`

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this properly soon.
My question about the .env file might be a silly one, but, am I suppose to create a .env file on my git? So that is different than my local one? (none of them gets pushed or pulled)

Comment: .env would be a file at the root of your project. On my project, I add .env to my .gitignore to prevent it from existing in my public repo.

Comment: that's the bit that I don't get... Let's say I run a pipeline in GitLab that generates static pages of my site, how can the repo access the api url if it's only declared on my local .env file?